# How to add new activity's children into another activity's children

Tags: android, android-activity, android-relativelayout

I want to add one Activity in to my current Activity's RelativeLayout(Parent) after a click on a Button. I want to do it dynamically, not from xml file. I'd like to know how and where to attach the code, and how would the code look. A simple example would do.

Comment: Do you mean `Fragment`?

Comment: Do you mean by **Fragments** or you want to change the **layout** only

Comment: with FrameLayout, we can add new fragment in current activity's children element. But, I am just wondering, is it possible to add whole new activity as one of the child of current activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments are the way to do this if your target API allows.  An Activity is not a View, and has a very different life cycle.

That said, the deprecated TabActivity is an Activity that appears inside a TabHost - so it isn't impossible.  But TabActivity is (I'm guessing) probably supported via nasty internal hacks that can't be generally supported by normal Activities.

Comment: And if your target API is less than 11, you can always use the support library! :)